# Is it possible to insert a python list to np array?

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is for nd_array[0] = 1,2,3,4,5
I have sat on this problem for hours now. I have attempted to create the whole 2D list as a list and then using np.asarray(just creates the strangiest array i havbe ever seen, not even sure how to explain it) , I've tried np.append this is just a cut out from a different problem. In the actual example, I am looping and creating a list with 5 values, then adding those values to nparray[0] then the loop after adding to nparray[1]

```
nd_array = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5))

pyth_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

np.insert(nd_array, pyth_list, 0)


print(123)
```

Comment: `nd_array[0] = pyth_list`

Comment: `np.insert(nd_array, pyth_list, 0)` this obviously doesn't do anything since `np.insert` doesn't mutate inplace, but instead returns a new array. I also don't know what this `print(123)` has to do with anything?

Comment: The way I normally figure out how something works in programming, especially in small extracted programs like these, is to use the debugger and inspect how elements change. the final line means that it wont finish the debugging once i click F8 after the np.insert() line and also lets me put a breakpoint there to inspect faster without having to click F8 @ruohola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
nd_array[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nd_array
```

output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: it's just that easy. 1-2hours well spent

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's as simple as:

```
import numpy as np

nd_array = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5))
pyth_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

nd_array[0] = pyth_list
print(nd_array)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **vstack()**

```
nd_array = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5))

pyth_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

np.vstack([pyth_list,nd_array])
```